# Quickly cycle across color schemes in Sublime Text 2/3

Tags: windows, colors, sublime-text-3

I'm using Sublime Text 3, soda theme, in Windows 8.1. I'm currently dealing with some syntax highlightings that are not yet fully tested, so some functions get too faded or grey in some color schemes provided by the editor, specially when I'm looking at selected text. So I have to keep changing until I can see correctly and comfortably.

But changing the color schemes is actually a tedious process: we have to navigate to the preferences menu either with the mouse or some long key combinations (such as Alt+P, right, up 3, right, then down until we reach the desired scheme).

Is there a configurable key binding setting to quickly switch to the previous or next color scheme in list? This is because Sublime Text is all about productivity and speed! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally tried it (the only color scheme I truly like is [my own](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme)) but it looks like the [`Camaleón`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Camaleon) plugin, available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net), is just what you're looking for. You can configure which color schemes you want to cycle through, then easily switch them with <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> will give you a random one out of all the ones you have installed, not just those in the list.

It claims to work with both ST2 and ST3. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt, I think this is exactly what I was looking for! By the way, I installed your Neon color scheme. Seems nice!